# How to say "You’re lucky that I found you when I did"?

Tags: expressions

{ The repetition of the same verb }

> You’re lucky that I found you **when I did**.
>
> Tu as eu de la chance que je t'aie trouvé **quand je t'ai trouvé**.

In English, you’ll never say: "You’re lucky that I found you **when I found you**", since this kind of repetition is shunned. So I suppose that my suggested French sentence above needs to be altered accordingly, though I’m not sure how.

The same goes for the following:

> Thank you so much for coming with us **as far as you did**. {You never say "**as far as you came**"}
>
> Un grand merci pour nous avoir accompagnés **aussi loin que... ???**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it is obvious you found someone precisely when you found someone, there might be no reason to add this detail so you might then simply say:

> *Tu as eu de la chance que je t'aie trouvé(e).*

If what you mean is the time you found him is important, you can say:

> *Tu as eu de la chance que je t'aie trouvé(e) à ce moment là*.
>
> *Tu as eu de la chance que je t'aie trouvé(e) au bon moment*.

About the second sentence, here are some suggestions:

> *Un grand merci pour nous avoir accompagnés jusque-là*.
>
> *Un grand merci pour nous avoir accompagnés à ce point*.
>
> *Un grand merci pour nous avoir autant accompagnés*.
>
> *Un grand merci pour nous avoir accompagnés autant que vous avez pu le faire*.

Comment: To @jlliagre   How do the following sentences sound? Do they still come across as redundant? Merci. "Tu as eu de la chance que je t'aie trouvé **quand je l'ai fait**." "Un grand merci pour nous avoir accompagnés **aussi loin que vous l'avez fait.**"

Comment: The first sentence is very unlikely to be used by a native French speaker. It might be misunderstood to mean "You are lucky that I found you when I did something (else)". The second one is all right.